# Relationship between concepts in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm developing a budgeting app using Domain Driven Design. I'm new to DDD and therefore need a validation of my design.

Here are the concepts I came up with:

- Transaction - which is either income or expense, on annual or monthly or one-off etc. basis.
- Budget - which is the calculated income, expenses and balance projection, divided into occurrences (say e.g. 12 months over the next year, based on the Transactions).

I made the Transaction the Entity and Aggregate Root. In my mind it has identity, it's a concrete planned expense or income that I know I'll receive, for a concrete thing, and I also need to persist it, so I can calculate the budget based on all my transactions.

Now, I have an issue with the Budget. It depends on my concrete list of Transactions. If one of the Transactions gets deleted, the budget will need to be re-calculated (seems like a good candidate for a domain event?). It's a function of my identifiable transactions at any given time.

Nothing outside the Aggregate boundary can hold a reference to anything inside, except to the root Entity. Which makes me think the budget is the Aggregate Root as it cannot be a ValueObject or Entity within the Transaction.

What's confusing is that I don't necessarily need to persist the budget (unless I want to cache it). I could calculate it from scratch on request, and send it over to the client app. 2 different budgets could have the same number of occurrences, incomes, expenses and balances (but not Transactions). Perhaps an argument for making it a ValueObject?

So, my questions is - what is the Budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Domain context vs Aggregate

First element you get wrong is a point of details about DDD semantics. If there is only one object in your "aggregate", then it is not an aggregate. An aggregate is a structure made of *multiple* (2+) objects, with at least one being an entity and called the aggregate root. If a `TransactionRpository` returns a `Transaction` object that has no value object or entity, then `Transaction` is an entity but not an aggregate nor an aggregate root. If a `BudgetRepository` returns a `Budget` entity that includes a `Transaction` object, then `Budget` and `Transaction` form an aggregate, `Budget` being the aggregate root. If `Budget` and `Transaction` are returned from different repositories, then they form different *contexts*.

Context being the generic concept that can either be an aggregate or an entity.

## Contexts are linked to use cases

Second element you get wrong is that you are trying to design your domain model outside of your use cases context. Your application clearly manipulates both concepts of `Budget` and `Transactions`, but does your application handles uses cases for both (budget management and transaction management) ? If yes, are these uses case different in a way that implies different domain constraints ?

**If your application only handles Budget management**, or both but they share their business constraints, then you only need a single context, that manipulates both concepts in a single aggregate. In that situation, `Budget` is probably your root aggregate, and it's up to your mode and use cases to tell whether the `Transaction` is a value object or you need to access them by Id.

**If your application handles uses cases for both**, with different business constraints, then you should split your domain in two contexts, with two different models, one for the `Budget` management use cases, the other for the `Transaction` management use cases.

## Polysemic domain model

The third element you get wrong, is that you are trying to build a single, unified, normalized domain model. This is wrong because it introduces very complex structures, and a lot of business rules that are irrelevant to your business cases. Why would you need to manipulate the `Budget` domain model when the use case does not need knowledge of the `Budget` concept or linked business rules ?

If your application has use cases for both concepts, you need two models. The `Budget` management model should not use the `Transaction` management model. However, that does not implies that the `Budget` model is not allowed to manipulate the `Transaction` concept and vice versa. It only means you must write another model for that. You could have a `Budget` context that manipulates `Budget` and `BudgetTransaction` models, and `Transaction` context that manipulates `Transaction` and `TransactionBudget` models. These models can map to the same RDBMS tables with different columns, relevant to their use cases, implementing relevant business rules.

This is called writing a *polysemic domain model*.

## Conclusion

> So, my questions is - what is the Budget?

It is not possible to answer definitely your last question, as the answer depends on the use cases your application handles. However, you mention the following constraint:

> If one of the Transactions gets deleted, the budget will need to be re-calculated

This seems a very good argument in favor of making your application as a single context application, based on an aggregate with `Budget` being the aggregate root and `Transaction` being an entity in the aggregate.

If you don't need to, try to refrain from splitting these two concepts in different contexts, unless you have very good reasons to do so: they manipulate excluding columns, they manipulate excluding business rules, you are interested  in deploying these two in different bounded contexts, different services, as they would scale differently, etc ...

Having business constraints that span accross multiple contexts implies a complex implementation based on domain events, 2-phase commits, saga pattern, etc ... It's a lot of work, you should balance that work with the benefits you expect in return.

Comment: According to some authors, aggregate can have a single entity being the root. What do you mean by "If Budget and Transaction are returned from different repositories, then they form different contexts"? Context boundaries are linked to use cases as per your second point, but you can have multiple aggregates and therefore repositories in a single bounded context. Anyway, I'll accept because I get most of your points even if I disagree with some semantics.